# Inspiration behind Jack Vance's fantasy names?

Tags: inspiration, name-significance, jack-vance, lyonesse-trilogy

One of my favourite parts of Jack Vance's *Lyonesse* series, which I first read many years ago, is the way the names seem perfectly chosen to reflect the nature of what they're naming. How could Tantrevalles be anything except a forest, or Tintzin Fyral anything but a castle, or the Teach tac Teach anything but a mountain range? Now I wonder if these names were adapted or inspired from real ones, which would explain how natural they seem.

**Did Vance ever speak about the inspiration behind his names?** Or is there any information or evidence for where they might have come from? (I'm mostly interested in names, either of places or people, from his *Lyonesse* trilogy, which is the only Vance fiction I've actually read, but information related to names in his other fantasy could also be interesting if it can be argued to be relevant.)